# List, Array or what else?

Tags: .net, arrays, list, data-structures, f#

I need a dynamic length data structure with the capability of changing the element values. 
The order of the elements is not important.

- If I use an array I can modify my elements, but I have problems with the length. The solution is to create a new array of the correct size and copy all the elements into the new one each time. Not a great idea because the number of elements changes often.
- It's better to use a generic list, but the modify process is really complicated: first of all I need to remove the element I want to change- the generic list doesn't seem to have a simple "Remove"/"Delete" method, so I tried the "Filter" one- then add the modified element to the head. It works but it's a bit too complicated for something so easy.

Is there a data structure that allows me to dynamically change the length and modify the elements such as a modifiable list or a dynamically-sized array?

Comment: What's the importance of the head if the element order does not matter?  If you add a property datetime modified to your object and make sure this changes when the object does, then the sorteddictionary should work.

Comment: As others said, `ResizeArray` matches your requirements, although that is usually sign of too imperative F# code. However, you did not say _why_ you need such data structure, so maybe there is an alternative solution to your actual problem that would be more functional. Can you give some details about that?

Comment: @Tomas - I don't like the implication that everyone who uses imperative code in F# needs to be coached out of it, and that functional is always better.

Comment: @Brian - I definitely did not want to imply that. I use mutable collections all the time :-) and I think the pragmatic style of F# is really valuable. However, I think it is good to use less mutation when learning F# as you can better appreciate functional concepts that way. I should have added this context in my first comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [ResizeArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353447.aspx). It's an abbreviation for the CLI type [List(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) which offers the features you require, like [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx) for example.

From MSDN Library:

> The List(T) class is the generic equivalent of the ArrayList class. It
>   implements the IList(T) generic interface using an array whose size is
>   dynamically increased as required.
>
> Methods such as Contains, IndexOf, LastIndexOf, and **Remove** use an
>   equality comparer for the list elements. The default equality comparer
>   for type T is determined as follows. If type T implements the
>   IEquatable(T) generic interface, then the equality comparer is the
>   Equals(T) method of that interface; otherwise, the default equality
>   comparer is Object.Equals(Object).
>
> Methods such as BinarySearch and Sort use an ordering comparer for the
>   list elements. The default comparer for type T is determined as
>   follows. If type T implements the IComparable(T) generic interface,
>   then the default comparer is the CompareTo(T) method of that
>   interface; otherwise, if type T implements the nongeneric IComparable
>   interface, then the default comparer is the CompareTo(Object) method
>   of that interface. If type T implements neither interface, then there
>   is no default comparer, and a comparer or comparison delegate must be
>   provided explicitly.
>
> **The List(T) is not guaranteed to be sorted.** You must sort the List(T)
>   before performing operations (such as BinarySearch) that require the
>   List(T) to be sorted.
>
> Elements in this collection can be accessed using an integer index.
>   Indexes in this collection are zero-based.
>
> List(T) accepts a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) as a valid
>   value for reference types and allows duplicate elements.

An example in `F#`:

```
open System

// an integer list
let intList =
    let temp = new ResizeArray<int>() in
    temp.AddRange([| 1; 2; 3 |]);
    temp

// print each int using the ForEach member method
intList.ForEach( fun i -> Console.WriteLine(i) )

// unpack items from the resize array
let itemOne = intList.Item(0)
let itemTwo = intList.[1]
```

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend to use [ResizeArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353447.aspx). It is basically [System.Collections.Generic.List<'T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353447.aspx) which is perfect to use if number of elements changes frequently.

```
// Add items to a ResizeArray based on a condition
let filterRange predicate (i, j) =
    let results = ResizeArray(j-i+1) // reserve enough memory
    for k = i to j do
        if predicate k then results.Add(k)
    results
```

Regarding your second concern, you still can use the syntax `arr.[idx] <- e` as with `Array`.

To avoid complicated manipulation of `ResizeArray`, you could use high-order functions in [ResizeArray module](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp.powerpack/microsoft.fsharp.collections.resizearray.html) from [F# PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/). These functions create new `ResizeArray`s so performance is not ideal.

```
// Use high-order functions to update items
let changeOneToThree (a: ResizeArray<_>) =
   ResizeArray.map (fun x -> if x = 1 then 3 else x) a
```

However, you can always start from there and optimize by mutating current `ResizeArray`.